# CData section is lost when xslt transformation is applied

Tags: xslt, cdata

part of my xslt transformation rule:

```
<xsl:if test="boolean(userSearch)">
    <xsl:copy-of select="userSearch"/>
</xsl:if>
```

In input file I have:

```
<userSearch>
    <baseDn><![CDATA[ou=T10 Entitlement,dc=mycompany,dc=com]]></baseDn>
    <filter><![CDATA[(objectClass=person)]]></filter>
    <scope>SUBTREE</scope>
    <identifierAttribute><![CDATA[cn]]></identifierAttribute>
</userSearch>
```

In output file I have CDATA lots:

```
<userSearch>
  <baseDn>ou=T10 Entitlement,dc=mycompany,dc=com</baseDn>
  <filter>(objectClass=person)</filter>
  <scope>SUBTREE</scope>
  <identifierAttribute>cn</identifierAttribute>
</userSearch>
```

What might be the reason?

Comment: not sure if this is a duplicate so I'm not flagging it... but have you taken a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963633/how-to-get-cdata-from-xml-node-using-xsl ?

Comment: maybe but that answer is a bit messy. not sure it could help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. The short answer is:

We should declare which tags consist CDATA using `cdata-section-elements` atrribute in your `<xsl:output` section.

Basically we should enlist all tags we want to be safe in terms of saving `CDATA` in it while transforming.

Like this:

```
<xsl:output
  method="xml"
  indent="yes"
  version="1.0"
  encoding="UTF-16"
  standalone="yes"
  cdata-section-elements="baseDn filter scope cn member"
/>
```

Actually, I found this answer here: http://www.bernzilla.com/2008/02/12/utilizing-cdata-section-elements-in-xsl/

---

**EDIT:**

After having comments below I prepared small test:

Actually CDATA DO helps, but not for all cases:

public class Escaping {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String result = "]]>/\\hello<>";  // this line is killing for CDATA if not escaping

    //result = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(result);  // we have to use escaping in any case

    String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";

    // CDATA does not help
    xml += "<tag><![CDATA[" + result + "]]></tag>"; // even if we  use CDATA

    //xml += "<tag>" + result + "</tag>"; // this is ok if 'result' is escaped

    System.out.println(xml);

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    doc.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("utf-8"))));

    System.out.println("well formed");

}
```

}

Comment: Well, close.  But XSLT processors will always produce well-formed XML output if you are using the XML output method (and if you are not making strenuous efforts to defeat them), so the cdata-section-elements attribute is *not* making those elements "safe" for arbitrary content; they are already "safe" in the sense that no content in them will make the output ill-formed.  The cdata-section-elements attribute is instead specifying how the elements should be serialized: using CDATA sections, instead of by escaping left angle brackets and ampersands as needed.

Comment: I use CDATA because othewhise my XML looks like this: <tag>fgfh\/></tag> what I believe is not safe, having such data in XML file. My task, though is: do transformation: if previous version of file had CDATA, then transformed version should have CDATA also, as well as the data itself.

Comment: @ses - not necessarily. Many people tend to abuse CDATA and apply too liberally. If the content/information is the same, it should not matter whether CDATA is used. XML-aware tools work on the XML-infoset, not on the angle brackets and characters. That is how you can substitute entity references for specific characters and it still "means" the same and will be evaluated by XML tools the same.

Comment: If you're working with conforming XML tools, `<tag>fgfhV></tag>` is perfectly 'safe'; avoiding it is totemism.  If you're working with tools that break on input like that, junk them unless you wrote them yourself for a very good reason.

Comment: If I have HTML form that allows symbols like "<" to be entered and saved then to XML file, I should care about the result. This is my 'tool'. I can not junk it.

Comment: @ses you should use an XML library to "save them to XML file", this will ensure that the result is well-formed XML (either by escaping `<` and `&` as entity references or by using a CDATA section).  If you just concatenate bits of text together using a tool that is not XML aware then you can't be certain the result will be XML.

Comment: Ok. you are right. I've put an edit about it. So you may put one "vote up" back :)